# Given $f(x) = x^3 − 3x^2 − 1$, $x \geq 2$, find $f^{−1} {'} (−1)$

Tags: derivatives, inverse, inverse-function

> Given $f(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 -1, x\ge2$, find $f^{-1}{'}(-1)$

I know I should show work I have done on this question when I ask on stackexchange but I literally get stucked at the beginning. I cannot find the inverse of this function and needless to say the derivative of it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to find the algebraic expression of $f^{-1}(x)$

You just need the derivative of the inverse at $x=-1$

So you calculate where $f(x)=-1;\;x\ge 2$ solving

$$x^3-3 x^2-1=-1;\;x\ge 2\to x=3$$
And apply the rule of the derivative of the inverse
$$f^{{-1}'}(-1)=1/f'(3)$$
As $f'(x)=3x^2-6x$ we have $f'(3)=9$ and finally
$$f^{{-1}'}(-1)=1/9$$